# Mapping through an array using react Hooks - REFACTORING CODE

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am doing a bit of practice and built a few apis to interact with via my front end. I have now refactored my code to use hooks. However, I am getting the error "games.map" is not a function with my map method.

ERROR BELOW

```
TypeError: games.map is not a function
Games
src/components/pages/games/Games.js:29
  26 |     </div>
  27 |   </div>
  28 | </div>
> 29 | <div className="text-white text-dark">
     | ^  30 |   {games.map(game => {
  31 |     return <GameCard games={game} key={game.name} />;
  32 |   })}
View compiled
▶ 17 stack frames were collapsed.
(anonymous function)
src/components/pages/games/Games.js:14
  11 | 
  12 | const fetchAllGames = () => {
  13 |   api.getAllGames().then(games => {
> 14 |     gameState({ games });
     | ^  15 |   });
  16 | };
  17 | 
View compiled
This screen is visible only in development. It will not appear if the app crashes in production.
Open your browser’s developer console to further inspect this error.
```

See below component in which I am trying to map through, any help with the map refactoring would be great :)

```
import * as api from '../../../api';
import GameCard from '../gameCards/GameCards';

const Games = () => {
  const [games, gameState] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchAllGames();
  });

  const fetchAllGames = () => {
    api.getAllGames().then(games => {
      gameState({ games });
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="container-fluid" style={{ height: 35 }}>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col">
            <button to="" className="btn btn-primary">
              Add New Game
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="text-white text-dark">
        {games.map(game => {
          return <GameCard games={game} key={game.name} />;
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Games;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution :

Since useState has Array as initialState
You should use `gameState(games)` instead of `gameState{games}`

```
const fetchAllGames = () => {
    api.getAllGames().then(games => {
      gameState( games );
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

.map only works in arrays, **not objects**

```
   api.getAllGames().then(games => {
      gameState({ games });
    });
```

in here you are setting state game with an object.

I have no idea what *games* contain, but if it is **an array** you should do it like this

```
gameState(games)
```